# Now that gravitational waves have been discovered, what does their particle version look like?

Tags: wave-particle-duality, gravitational-waves

Duality dictates that gravitational waves should have a particle counterpart too, right? Will this in any way help solve the big problem of quantum gravity?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/215173/what-is-the-difference-between-gravitons-and-gravitational-waves

Comment: The same thing it looked like last week. Seriously. We had this theory; it could be written in several ways. It made some prediction. Another one of those predictions was borne out experimentally (many others have already been done). But that doesn't suddenly change the theory or the previously completed work.